# files in QtResource files not found

Tags: c++, qt

I have several XML files in a Qt Resource file. Everything works great on Linux.  But on Windows, at runtime, it appears the Resource file does not have anything in it, at all.  The qrc cpp file is built, and is sufficiently large enough so I am guessing all the files I want have been built into it.

I originally created the Resource file using Qt Creator on Linux. Using Qt Creator on Windows I can open the XML files from the Resource file.

I am using this line to access them:

```
QDirIterator it( ":", QStringList() << "*.xml", QDir::Files );
```

For testing purposes, I tried this:

```
QDir qDir( ":" );
QStringList listFiles = qDir.entryList();
```

and looped through listFiles, but it just had some files that I read somewhere were the general things that were always there.

I'm certainly not a Qt expert by any means, and this is my first attempt to use Qt Resource files.  Why would this work on Linux but not Windows?

Here is the QRC:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>OMSClient____ActionDefinitions.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____ADGroupDefinitions.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____AdminConfiguration.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____AlertSetup.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____ClientConfigTooltips.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____ClientConfiguration.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____DALDBEditorConfiguration.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____DALDBEditorStartup.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____DBEditorConfiguration.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____DefaultViewSetup.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____GlobalSetup.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____HtmlFiles.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____Icons.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____MaintenanceModule.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____MenuTree.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____Modules.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____PermissionDefinitions.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____Pixmaps.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____ReportConfigurationSyntax.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____SpareAircraftModule.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____SSIDBEditorStartup.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient____SystemConfiguration.xml</file>
        <file>OMSClient_Guest_Guest__MenuTree.xml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I posted this same question in a Qt forum.  Somebody there asked me to create a test program showing the problem.  So naturally, the test program works correctly.

Comment: show your .qrc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in my application where the problem was, the resource file is being read in a lib that is linked into the exe.  So the way to make it work is in the main() make a call to `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(myResourceFile)`.